# Odoo One2many relation with VIEW table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, odoo-8

I have the following report model:

```
class crm_purchased_products(models.Model):
    _name = "crm.purchased_products"
    _description = "Most purchased products report"
    _auto = False

    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product')
    invoice_qty = fields.Integer('Number of invoices')
    quantity = fields.Integer('Quantity')
    total_amount_untaxed = fields.Float(string='Total amount', digits=dp.get_precision('Account'))


    def init(self, cr):
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, self._table)
        _query = """CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW crm_purchased_products AS (
            SELECT ail.partner_id AS partner_id, ail.product_id AS product_id, 
                COUNT(ail.invoice_id) AS invoice_qty, SUM(ail.quantity) AS quantity, 
                SUM(ail.price_subtotal) AS total_amount_untaxed, MAX(ai.date_invoice) AS last_purchase, 
                (MAX(ai.date_invoice) - MIN(ai.date_invoice))/COUNT(ail.invoice_id) AS days_between_purchases 
            FROM account_invoice_line AS ail 
            JOIN account_invoice AS ai ON ail.invoice_id = ai.id 
            WHERE ai.type = 'out_invoice' AND ai.state IN ('open','paid') 
            GROUP BY ail.partner_id, ail.product_id HAVING ail.product_id > 0 ORDER BY ail.partner_id ASC
        );
        """

    def search(self, cr, uid, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None,context=None, count=False):
        return super(crm_purchased_products, self).search(cr, uid, args=args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order,
        context=context, count=count)

crm_purchased_products()
```

**I want to insert as a `tree` field in `res.partner form view` to show only the products associated to the contact:**

```
<page name="internal_notes" string="Internal Notes">
                        <field name="purchased_products">
                            <tree string="Most purchased products">
                                <field name="partner_id" invisible="1"/>
                                <field name="product_id"/>
                                <field name="invoice_qty"/>
                                <field name="quantity"/>
                                <field name="total_amount_untaxed"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
```

But, when I try to relate it from `res.partner`:

```
purchased_products = fields.One2many('crm.purchased_products', 'partner_id', string='Purchased products', readonly=True, copy=True)
```

I get this error:

> ProgrammingError: relation "crm_purchased_products" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "crm_purchased_products".id FROM "crm_purchased_produ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID field is auto added to all models from `models.Model`, so you must get it. Try this:

```
def init(self, cr):
    tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, self._table)
    _query = """CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW crm_purchased_products AS (
        SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id, ail.partner_id AS partner_id, ail.product_id AS product_id, 
            COUNT(ail.invoice_id) AS invoice_qty, SUM(ail.quantity) AS quantity, 
            SUM(ail.price_subtotal) AS total_amount_untaxed, MAX(ai.date_invoice) AS last_purchase, 
            (MAX(ai.date_invoice) - MIN(ai.date_invoice))/COUNT(ail.invoice_id) AS days_between_purchases 
        FROM account_invoice_line AS ail 
        JOIN account_invoice AS ai ON ail.invoice_id = ai.id 
        WHERE ai.type = 'out_invoice' AND ai.state IN ('open','paid') 
        GROUP BY row_number() OVER (), ail.partner_id, ail.product_id HAVING ail.product_id > 0 ORDER BY ail.partner_id ASC
    );
    """
```

Comment: Your second answer is the correct one! The first turn to zero `days_between_purchases` because max and min dates are the same.

Comment: Ok, so I am going to remove the first one then.